# Came same DNS point to multiple backend systems based on path

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a domain name registered. www.mydomain.com. I server some paid content on my website. All the requests on all ports for this domain point to tomcat server deployed in Azure Linux VM. I have a requirement to migrate this application to another PaaS platform without affecting existing consumers. I want to first ensure the existing users run out of their subscription next year and on renewal i can migrate them onto new system.(give them new link).
But for now all the new consumers coming in need to be pointed to new backend system with the same Domain name. www.mydomain.com.
Is it possible to divert traffic based on a path? eg
www.mydomain.com/oldcontent will point to azure vm while www.mydomain.com/newcontent points to new PaaS runtime.

Comment: DNS works on a domain-level basis, and so you cannot point one path to a different server via DNS. You could always have the new runtime have another domain pointed to it, and then proxy requests for `/newcontent/*` to that domain via the `[P]` flag in `.htaccess`. Note, however, that this may slow down requests, and so is not advised. Depending on how existing comsumers connect, you could just use a new domain and point the old one over to it... Not sure how everything is set up, so this is just a guess at what you *could* do.

Comment: THanks. I will try that. If i move all their old content to new server. Can I redirect them to the new server instead? say for eg: /oldcontent/customer1/page1?param1=1&param2=2  pointing to /newcontent/nyx/customer1/page1......and in a similar way /customer2/page2... to /newcontent/nyx/customer2/page2. Where can i configure these redirections/

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud here, but considering the fact that existing customers will already be impacted when their service is renewed, why not just migrate them to the new platform anyway and safe yourself the hassle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.htaccess` if [Apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/) isn't served as a proxy before tomcat. If you are looking for something similar to Apache's mod_rewrite, then try [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), with that you shall try URL rewriting, forwarding/redirection or URL masking silently.